# Any results about auto-correlation function of Mertens function

Tags: prime-numbers, mobius-function, multiplicative-function

One can define $f(x) = M(e^x)/\sqrt{e^x}$, where $M$ is Mertens function. It looks like some sort of stationary random process (yes, I know it's not random process, see plot below), namely it lives mostly in the strip $y \in [-0.5, 0.5]$, and 'frequency' of crossing x-axis looks the same in different regions of x-axis.

But it behaves not like random walk process (normalized by sqrt(time)). Its quasi-auto-correlation function  $R(\tau, T, \epsilon)$ has oscillations (see plot below). This quasi-auto-correlation function $R(\tau, T, \varepsilon)$ is defined as following:
$$
R(\tau, T, \varepsilon) = \mathrm{E}(f(t) \cdot f(t + \tau'))\\ 
\;\;where \; t \in [0, T], \; \tau' \in [\tau, \tau + \varepsilon].
$$
Here $E$ stands for "expected value",  $t$ is randomly sampled from $[0, T]$, and $\tau'$ is sampled from $[\tau, \tau + \varepsilon]$. Result may depend on distribution on $[0, T]$, but numerical experiments show it does not much (~ conjecture that "random process is stationary").  Anyhow, let's use uniform distribution on $[0, T]$.

[Normalized Merten's function $f(t) = M(e^t)/\sqrt{e^t}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNdMW.jpg)

[Auto-correlation function  $R(t, T, \varepsilon)$ of  $f(t)$ for $T = \log(10^7)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbf6L.jpg)

Is there any known results on this quasi-auto-correlation function for this normalized Merten's function?

Namely, I wonder if limit $$\lim_{T\to \infty}R(t, T, \varepsilon)$$  exists for any $t$ and $\varepsilon$.
And limit $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\lim_{T\to \infty}R(t, T, \varepsilon)$$